# Скрыть все уведомления в Status Bar. Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Как сделать так, чтобы статус-бар как на первом скриншоте (Telegram X) стал в моём приложении?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл способ это сделать.
Необходимо добавить следующий код в метод `onCreate();`

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
```

Вот что у меня получилось в результате:
[image: Уведомления скрылись]